# SAS EG: project file version not supported

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

My project was saved by SAS EG 7.1 and now I can't open it by SAS EG 6.1.

Is there any way to open the project by older (6.1) SAS EG? Maybe there is some special option in SAS EG 7.1, that allow to save project for opening by older EG?

Comment: If it helps, EG projects, (last time) I looked were a mix of text and XML, encoded as 16 bit characters (Unicode I think) and zipped up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A egp file is a zip file with XML. Backward converting SAS EG projects can be done like this:

1. Rename the file to zip
2. Extract the file
3. Open the project.xml and replace all versions with 6.1 equivalents (see a 6.1 egp). Perhaps you need to replace versions in the EGTask folders.
4. Now copy all files back into the original zip (use something like winrar because windows zip doesn't work).
5. Rename it back to *.egp

When you open it in EG 6.1 you will get a warning about git, this you can ignore. If you save the project with another name then you will not get the warning anymore.

Comment: Wow, you are my hero! It's awesome!

Answer (score 2):

I have access here to both EG 6.1 and 7.1.  I do not see an option for saving the project in 7.1 to an earlier version.  My best guess would be to export all of the code from 7.1, and then re-open it all in 6.1.  Not ideal, but at least an option. Good luck!

File -> Export -> Export all code in project

Comment: This is pretty much your best option for back-converting a project.  One of the more frustrating elements of EGPs, in my opinion, their lack of backwards convertibility and frequent changes in format.